# how do I forward the templates arguments onto the std::make_unique when creating policy based class?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, policy-based-design

Lets assume I'm using ***policy based templates*** design pattern (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_C%2B%2B_Design).

I'm having some issue related to how would I use **std::make_shared** (or **std::make_unique** for that matter) for creating new type **Bar**, that has some optional template arguments.
If I don't want to change default policy, then that's no problem, simple line would work:

```
auto bar = std::make_unique<Bar>();
```

However if I want Bar accept different "policy" as template args, how can I pass them into std::make_unique ??

tried the following (with no luck):

```
auto bar = std::make_unique<Bar<Policy2, Policy3>>();
```

or:

```
auto bar = std::make_unique<Bar>(Policy2, Policy3);
```

Here are some sample code to demonstrate the problem:

```
// Bar.hpp
template<PolicyConcept1 T = policy1_default, PolicyConcept2 V = policy2_default>
class Bar
{
public:
    Bar();

private:
    // Data Members
    std::unique_ptr<T> _policy1;
    std::unique_ptr<V> _policy2;    
};
```

---

```
// bar.cpp
#include "bar.hpp"

template<PolicyConcept1 T, PolicyConcept2 V>
Bar<T, V>::Bar() :
_policy1{ std::make_unique<T>() },
_policy2{ std::make_unique<V>()}
{

}
```

---

```
// Foo.hpp
template<PolicyConcept1 T = policy1_default, PolicyConcept2 V = policy2_default>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo();

private:
    // Data Members
    std::unique_ptr<Bar> _bar;  

};
```

---

```
#include "Foo.hpp"


template<PolicyConcept1 T, PolicyConcept2 V>
Foo<T, V>::Foo() :
  // problem is here, how do I change the default policy and forward it into std::make_unique ??
    _bar{ std::make_unique<bar>() }
{

}
```

The question is inside initializer of Foo CTOR:
how do I forward the T & V template arguments onto the std::make_unique ??

appreciate any help :)

Comment: Why are you trying to store the policy as member variables in the object? By virtue of being template arguments, they are always available, that's one of the main advantages behind using policies in the first place: parametrize without increasing storage space.

Comment: You are right about increasing storage space.
I need the policy being member on some other manager class.

Comment: If you want to create policy class with some specific arguments, you will have to provide a constructor in `Foo`. If your class depends on just one policy, and requires no arguments on its own, you could just look at what [std::make_unique](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) does internally but that's cryptic, providing arguments to Foo which go to policy and not Foo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out.
It's turns out the syntax:

```
auto bar = std::make_unique<Bar<Policy2, Policy3>>();
```

works after all (on C++20, using MSVC v16.10.2).

It requires the following declaration to work:

```
std::unique_ptr<Bar<T,V>> _bar;
```

in addition I had to provide on CPP this as well (to avoid linker error):

```
template class Bar<concrete_policy1, concrete_policy2>;
```